# Current Location Android using WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have designed a simple browser for Android using `WebView`. Everything is working fine but when I open Google maps then my browser can't access the current location of the device. I don't understand what is going wrong.
also in manifest i have given the permission `ACCESS FINE LOCATION`
My code is:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView ourBrow=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        Button bgo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button res=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button gfo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        try{
            ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir///@20.3464436,85.8127819,15z");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            /*String myHtml = "<html><body>A very basic <b>WebView</b> demo!</body></html>";
            ourBrow.loadData(myHtml, "text/html", null);*/
        }
        bgo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(ourBrow.canGoBack())
                    ourBrow.goBack();
            }
        });
        gfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(ourBrow.canGoForward())
                    ourBrow.goForward();
            }
        });
        res.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir///@20.3464436,85.8127819,15z");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: no one will understand and could help you if you don't post your code explaining the problem area!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it is, there can be many reasons why this is happening; it's best to provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. That helps us to help you. As a side note, did you set the permissions right?

Comment: thank you sir, i am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- JavaScript must be enabled in the `WebView`, using
  `WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` The app needs permission
  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION The `WebView`must use a custom `WebChromeClient`
  which implements
  `WebChromeClient.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()`. This method
  is called by the WebView to obtain permission to disclose the user's
  location to JavaScript. (In the case of the browser, we show a prompt
  to the user.) The default implementation does nothing, so permission
  is never obtained and the location is never passed to JavaScript.`webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { 
  public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
  callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
  } 
  });`

Geolocation uses databases to persist cached positions and permissions between sessions. The location of the database is set using WebSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(...). If the location of the database is not set, the persistent storage will not be available, but Geolocation will continue to function correctly otherwise. To set the location of the databases, use ...

```
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath( context.getFilesDir().getPath() );
```